# Finding the most frequently-occurring values in a range of values in a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table in Oracle(12c) with many columns and one of the table column is 'Color'. 'Color' is not part of the primary key of that table. Currently the Color column values are as follows:

```
Color Column Values
red
red
green
green
green
blue
blue
blue
blue
pink
```

I need two information from the above data

i). An output like below

```
color    Freq
red        2
green      3
blue       4
pink       1
```

ii). The highest frequency of the 'Color' from the table data i.e

```
blue 4
```

How can I get those outputs?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple aggregate plus a Windowed Aggregate to find the max:

```
select color, freq
from
 ( select
      color, 
      count(*) freq, 
      max(count(*)) over () as max_freq
    from tab
    group by color
 ) dt
where freq = max_freq
```

Comment: There's no equivalent in Oracle of `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES`?

Comment: @ErikE: Why using a proprietary syntax if there's a much more flexible Standard SQL way? Instead of `TOP n WITH TIES` it's `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)` followed by `<= n`

Comment: @ErikE - since you tagged this as 12c then [yes there is](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA), but it's just syntactic sugar around this kind of analytic approach.

Comment: @dnoeth Oh, I'm not saying the proprietary syntax is better, but it's definitely shorter and more expressive of the intent. Also, having to do a windowing function over the entire set instead of just pick a few related rows seems like it is a lot of extra work for the engine. So I was curious as to what other options there might be.

Comment: @AlexPoole Since I tagged what as what? I am not the original poster.

Comment: @ErikE: It's shorter, but only usable for a very specific case, you can't get the 2nd highest value or the max per group. There's one specific thing I never liked about `TOP`: you must skip to the end of the Select to see if it's ordered (ranking) or not (kind of sample). And a decent optimizer should apply the same optimizations to get a fast result.

Comment: @ErikE - oops, sorry. Since the OP tagged the question as 12c... but since I'm here, [this blog post](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/12c-first-n/) shows the analytics under the hood.

Comment: @dnoeth Fair enough! One should be fluent enough in SQL to do the more complex constructions; I just wondered as I see value in shorter constructs for common use cases.

Comment: @ErikE: I usually prefer Standard SQL (unless it's too verbose). MS always tries to trap users in their proprietary syntax, of course without telling it's proprietary :-), e.g the new `IIF`, you save a few keystrokes over a similar `CASE WHEN`, but it's limited to one specific case.

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle 12c you can use a new syntax for top-n queries:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1#top-n
This new syntax is similar to `SELECT TOP x` or `LIMIT x` in another databases.

```
SELECT Color, count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY Color
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: Be aware that if there are two color values with the same top frequency value and you want all of the top records then this will not provide the correct response unless you add "WITH TIES".

Answer (score 0):

for i

```
select color, count(*) freq
from your_table
group by color
```

for ii

```
select color, freq 
from
(
select color, freq, max(freq) over() max_freq
from
(
select color, count(*) freq
from your_table
group by color
)
)
where freq = max_freq
```

Comment: There's no equivalent in Oracle of `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES`?